# CSS element beneath the dropzone

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created an infinite horizontal scrollbar. What happens is that I have the need to drag some elements to the dropzone, and they appear beneath the dropzone instead of above.

The html markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      Drop here
    </div>
    <div class="group-wrapper">
      <div class="group-list">
        <div class="group">Drag me</div>
        <div class="group">Drag me</div>
        <div class="group">Drag me</div>
        <div class="group">Drag me</div>
        <div class="group">Drag me</div>
        <div class="group">Drag me</div>
        <div class="group">Drag me</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.wrapper .header 
{
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 8px 4px 10px 8px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

.wrapper .group-wrapper 
{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 8px;
    top: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.wrapper .group-wrapper .group
{
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}
```

**By removing the lines** `overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto;` within the class `.group-wrapper` the draggable starts working perfectly but my scrollbars disappear.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3pyp7fz7/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your draggables appear behind the dropzone due to z-index stacking.

I'm guessing that the dropzone has a different [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) than the draggables, but I have not yet been able to determine exactly why. I'll update this answer if I figure that out.

In any case, I had some success by using the [`appendTo`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-appendTo) option for `draggable`. This option defines "[w]hich element the draggable helper should be appended to while dragging," which helps to overcome your issue with z-index stacking.

I've also changed the "helper" mode to "clone, because:

> Note: The appendTo option only works when the helper option is set to not use the original element.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.group').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: '#container',
    connectToSortable: ".header"
  });

  $(".header").droppable({
    accept: ".group",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var drop = $(this),
        drag = ui.draggable;
      drag.appendTo(drop);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F0F5F8;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div#container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
section#navigation {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #72B8F1;
  height: 30px;
}
section#navigation .navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
section#navigation .navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
section#content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
section#content .row {
  min-height: initial !important;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper .header {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px 4px 10px 8px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.wrapper .group-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 8px;
  top: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.group {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <section id="navigation">
    <div class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            Brand name
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
          Drop here
        </div>
        <div class="group-wrapper">
          <div class="group-list">
            <div class="group">Drag me 1</div>
            <div class="group">Drag me 2</div>
            <div class="group">Drag me 3</div>
            <div class="group">Drag me 4</div>
            <div class="group">Drag me 5</div>
            <div class="group">Drag me 6</div>
            <div class="group">Drag me 7</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use helper and clone.